# I am getting errors while installing NuxtJs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have been trying to install NuxtJs in my system installed and updated npm/npx still getting errors
this is my error log
i successfully installed Nuxt but i am getting erros while launching the app i.e when i type
`npm run dev`
i get these following errors

```
  ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮                                                                                     
  │                                       │                                                                                     
  │   Nuxt.js @ v2.13.3                   │                                                                                     
  │                                       │                                                                                     
  │   ▸ Environment: development          │                                                                                     
  │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │                                                                                     
  │   ▸ Target:      server               │                                                                                     
  │                                       │                                                                                     
  │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │                                                                                     
  │                                       │                                                                                     
  ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                
 Preparing project for development                                                                                              
 Initial build may take a while                                                                                                 
 Builder initialized                                                                                                            
 Nuxt files generated                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                
ERROR  Package exports for 'C:\Work\Projects\Appclust-SEO\Nuxt\node_modules\colorette' do not define a valid '.' target         
                                                                                                                                
 at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:545:13)                                                                
 at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:459:14)                                                                        
 at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)                                                                      
 at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)                                                           
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)                                                    
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)                                                               
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)                                                                      
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)                                                                             
 at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:5:17)                                                     
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)                                                                    
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)                                                      
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)                                                                         
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)                                                               
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)                                                                      
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)                                                                             
 at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\postcss-preset-env\index.js:5:36)
```

I can still access the app but with these errors what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue actually occurs with Node version 13.0.1. check your node version, if it same with this, try installing the latest node version or at least v14.15.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't install nuxt in your system. You can just install it for a specific project. Run ***npx create-nuxt-app .*** in a folder and then run ***npm run dev***

Comment: You need to provide more information about what is in your terminal, code or files structure so we can answer that.